# How to solve 3-13 (last piece of Old Ruins) in normal mode?

Tags: nightsky

Here's the bit in question:

[image: Y U NO DEFAULT TO PNG, PAINT]

- If I drop any of the wheels first, they'll all simply fall in the bottomless pit.
- If I drop the bar onto the two wheels, I'll have a stable cart that's of no use whatsoever, and then I'm back to square one.
- If I drop the bar onto the single cart, everything falls down.
- If I lose all the wheels and drop the bar, the bar will not support my weight and I'll be amusingly propelled towards the general direction whence I came.
- If I destroy the supports in a clockwise direction starting from the top one, I'll end up with the bottom wheel supporting the bar in some kind of landing ramp... that's too far to be of use.
- If I destroy the supports in a counter-clockwise direction from the top one skipping bottom, I'll get a single-wheel supported ramp upon which I can propel myself... and end in the one space gap at the right.

What am I supposed to do here?

Answer (score 1):

Drop the supports in this order: top, left. Hold <kbd>S</kbd> and push right all the way.

[image]

It is important to not remove the marked block, or you'll end up down the dash area.

This ends the hard part of 3-13, but there's two more... er... screenfuls left. By now you should know the hard way that you need to hold left to go right if you're rotating against the ceiling. Luckily this means you can clear all jumps by simply holding <kbd>S</kbd>, heading in the direction you need to go and keeping hold until you land on a horizontal surface. Use <kbd>A</kbd> to complete the top left hand corner section, or you'll end up to square one.

Simply rotate your way out of the third screenful to kiss the old ruins goodbye.